# Virtualenv: pip not installing Virtualenv in the correct directory

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, sudo

Whenever I try running virtualenv, it returns command not found.

Per recommendations in other posts, I have tried installing virtualenv with both *$ pip install virtualenv* and *$ sudo pip install virtualenv*. I have uninstalled and tried again multiple times.

I think the issue is that I am using OSX, and pip is installing virtualenv in */Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages*. As I understand, it should be installed in */usr/local/bin/*.

How can I install virtualenv there?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install virtualenv`

Comment: What is the output of `env` for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install it at */usr/local/bin/* you can add `--target=` argument to `pip` call:

```
sudo pip install --target=/usr/local/bin virtualenv
```

Comment: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/virtualenv-15.1.0.dist-info'

Comment: sudo pip install --target=/usr/local/bin virtualenv

Comment: @CarlesMitjans Update your answer.

Comment: It did install, but the command not found error hasn't gone away.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `/usr/local/share/python` in `/etc/launchd.conf` and `~/.bashrc`. This might resolve the issue you are facing.

Comment: how might I do that?

Comment: Edit the above given two files using editors like `vim` and add the given path at the end of the file. You need to open `/etc/launchd.conf` with root access.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on Ubuntu 16.04 (using Python 2.7)

*case user shell:*

```
$ (VirtualEnvironment) sudo pip install <package>
```

that installs in systemwide libs

*case root shell (sudo su -):*

```
# (VirtualEnvironment) pip install <package>
```

installs in the VIRTUALENV_HOME/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

I'm installing for different applications under /var/www/ (each one in a different subdir)